# TikaException: Failed to close temporary resource while parsing PDF

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tika on Windows 10, jre 1.8.0_241, and I've imported Tika 1.24.1 using ant. I have the code below to extract content from a PDF:

```java
public class TikaExtraction {
    
   public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException {

      //Assume sample.txt is in your current directory              
      File file = new File("C:\\Users\\myPC\\Desktop\\testPDF.pdf");
      
      //Instantiating Tika facade class
      Tika tika = new Tika();
      String filecontent = tika.parseToString(file);
      System.out.println("Extracted Content: " + filecontent);
      
   }         
}
```

Getting below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Failed to close temporary resources
    at org.apache.tika.io.TemporaryResources.dispose(TemporaryResources.java:174)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:150)
    at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:527)
    at com.oracle.cegbu.filesearch.service.kafka.TikaExtraction.main(TikaExtraction.java:28)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Local\Temp\apache-tika-6518312717498705085.tmp: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tika.io.TemporaryResources$1.close(TemporaryResources.java:84)
    at org.apache.tika.io.TemporaryResources.close(TemporaryResources.java:145)
    at org.apache.tika.io.TemporaryResources.dispose(TemporaryResources.java:172)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: There is another application that is using `C:\Users\myPC\AppData\Local\Temp\apache-tika-6518312717498705085.tmp`  It's possible you may have a hanging process that is not closing that file. Check for any runtimes might be doing this.

Comment: Could your Virus Checker be getting in the way and keeping the file open?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to use the inputStream instead of File in try-in-resources

```
public class TikaExtraction {
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, TikaException {

    //Assume sample.txt is in your current directory     
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\myPC\\Desktop\\testPDF.pdf");

    //Instantiating Tika facade class
    try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        String filecontent = tika.parseToString(inputStream);
        System.out.println("Extracted Content: " + filecontent);
    }
    
}
```

}